# Missing method in mred:canvas%?

Tags: scheme, racket

I used [MrEd Designer](http://hexahedron.hu/personal/peteri/mreddesigner/index.html) to make a user interface for a Scheme program.  It includes a mred:canvas% on which I'd like to plot points using `draw-point`.  It's defined as:

```
(define (naca-ui-init
         {...}
         #:airfoil-canvas-class
         (airfoil-canvas-class canvas%)
         {...})
```

and later:

```
(set! airfoil-canvas
        (new
         airfoil-canvas-class
         (parent vertical-pane-2165)
         (horiz-margin 0)
         (min-width 350)
         (vert-margin 0)
         (gl-config #f)
         (stretchable-width #t)
         (enabled #t)
         (stretchable-height #t)
         (min-height 175)
         (label "Canvas")
         (style '(border))))
```

When I try to `(send airfoil-canvas draw-point 15 30)`, however, I get:

```
send: no such method: draw-point for class: canvas%

 === context ===
/usr/local/lib/racket/collects/racket/private/class-internal.rkt:4543:0: obj-error
/home/jason/NACA/naca-ui.scm:29:8: plot-point
/home/jason/NACA/naca.scm:225:23
/home/jason/NACA/naca-ui.scm:21:10: inner
```

Am I misreading the [documentation](http://www.cs.rice.edu/CS/PLT/packages/53/doc/mred/node140.htm#SECTION00560000000000000000), or is there something else I don't get here?

PS: Can someone with more rep add the tag MrEd?  It would be pertinent here, but you need 1500 to add new tags.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you should try the [Racket mailing list](http://racket-lang.org/community.html).

Comment: Done.  If I get a good answer there, I'll summarize it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: in short, my docs were moldy and I should have used http://docs.racket-lang.org/.  From there, it was easy to see that:

```
(send airfoil-canvas draw-point 15 30)
```

should have been:

```
(send (send airfoil-canvas get-dc) draw-point 15 30)
```

You need to do your drawing on a drawing-context these days.